# Caching Python function results using only subset of arguments as identifier

Tags: python, memoization, functools

Is there an easy way to cache function results in python based on a single identifier argument? For example, suppose my function has 3 arguments `arg1`, `arg2` and `id`. Is there a simple way to cache the function result based only on the value of `id`? That is, whenever `id` takes the same value, the cached function would return the same result, regardless of `arg1` and `arg2`.

**Background:**
I have a time-consuming and repeatedly called function, in which `arg1` and `arg2` are lists and dictionaries composed of large numpy arrays. Hence, `functools.lru_cache` doesn't work as is. Yet, there are only a handful specific combinations of `arg1` and `arg2`. Hence my idea to manually specify some `id` which takes a unique value for each possible combination of `arg1` and `arg2`.

Comment: Yes, it's easy to write your own memoization based only on one argument of a function.  Just need the argument to be hashable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def cache(fun):
    cache.cache_ = {}
    def inner(arg1, arg2, id):
        if id not in cache.cache_:
            print(f'Caching {id}') # to check when it is cached
            cache.cache_[id] = fun(arg1, arg2, id)
        return cache.cache_[id]
    return inner
    
@cache
def function(arg1, arg2, arg3):
    print('something')
```

You can create your own decorator as suggested by DarrylG. You can do a `print(cache.cache_)` inside `if id not in cache.cache_:` to check that it only caches for newer values of `id`.

You can make `cache_` a function attribute [PEP 232](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0232/) by using `cache.cache_`. Then when you want to reset `cache_` you can use `cache.cache_.clear()`. That will give you direct access to the dictionary that caches the results.

```
function(1, 2, 'a')
function(11, 22, 'b')
function(11, 22, 'a')
function([111, 11], 222, 'a')

print(f'Cache {cache.cache_}') # view previously cached results
cache.cache_.clear() # clear cache
print(f'Cache {cache.cache_}') # cache is now empty

# call some function again to populate cache
function(1, 2, 'a')
function(11, 22, 'b')
function(11, 22, 'a')
function([111, 11], 222, 'a')
```

Edit:
Addressing a new comment by @Bob (OP), in most cases returning a reference to the same object would suffice but OP's use-case seems to require a new copy of the answer, possibly due to the nature of `function(arg1, arg2, arg3)` being treated as unique based on `arg1`, `arg_2` and `arg3` (inside the "`cache`" function uniqueness is only defined using `id`). In which case, returning the same reference to a mutable object would lead to undesired behavior. As mentioned in the same comment, the return statement in the `inner` function should be changed from `return cache.cache_[id]` to `return copy.deepcopy(cache.cache_[id])`.

Comment: This is great. One follow up question: How would I best clear cache_ without reloading the module that houses the definition of cache? I tried adding a keyword argument to cache `def cache(fun, clear=False)` with the idea of adding an if statement that clears the cache when calling `cache(None,  clear=True)`. But it seems that `cache_` is always empty when I am calling cache directly.

Comment: Yes, that's perfect and I even learned some more python from it. Thanks

Comment: After continued use of this (still working great!), I think it might be better to return a `deepcopy` of `cache.cache_[id]`. Otherwise, the cached results may get inadvertently overwritten if some of the function outputs are mutable.

Comment: good to know my answer still works :D, that is a good point, I will edit this once I am on a PC, but appreciate the feedback @Bob

Comment: Yes, that's how I did it, too. I think this is better behavior for any kind of caching function, because otherwise the output to future `fun` calls will change if the *output* to prior calls is ever modified. E.g, `my_cached_list = make_unsorted_list(id='my_id')` will fail to return the original value of `cache_` (say, an unsorted list), if one ever did `my_cached_list.sort()` after a prior call to the caching function. While perhaps desirable in some cases, it would be unexpected in most use cases. @python_user

Answer (score 1):

I think you could move excessive arguments to a separate function (caller), like below:

```py
import functools

def get_and_update(a, b, c):
    return {'a': a, 'b': b, 'c': c}

# ->

@functools.lru_cache
def get_by_a(a):
    return {}

def get_and_update(a, b, c):
    res = get_by_a(a)
    res.update(a=a, b=b, c=c)
    return res

x1 = get_and_update('x', 1, 2)
x2 = get_and_update('x', 2, 3)
assert x1 is x2
print(x1, x2, sep='\n')
```

```
{'a': 'x', 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
{'a': 'x', 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
```